# How to get the value with GSON / Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

How to extract the value of "text" by using GSON/Retrofit?

```
    {
       code: 200,
       lang: "en-ms",
       text: [
           "Burung"
       ]
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to make the API call successfully?

Comment: yes, the API call  sucessfully

Comment: Please try to google ‘how to use POJO with retrofit’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 Create your model class**

```
public class ResponseItem {

/**
 * code : 200
 * lang : en-ms
 * text : ["Burung"]
 */

private int code;
private String lang;
private List<String> text;

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getLang() {
    return lang;
}

public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
}

public List<String> getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(List<String> text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

}

**2 inside your Retrofit method response :**

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
  ResponseItem responseItem;
  responseItem = response.body(); }
```

and you can call text by saying responseitem.Get("whatever u want from the model class")

Comment: it work on me thank you and how could i remove the "[]"

Answer (score 2):

text there like Map. You need to create pojo with

```
@SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private int mCode;

@SerializedName("lang")
    @Expose
    private String mLang;

@SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    private Map <String, List<String> mText;
```

Create Retrofit with factory (GsonFactory). And instantiate this pojo.

p.s: also you can make serializator and deserializator for your objects

Answer (score 1):

make POJO class of given response and register this in retrofit callback and get values with the help of getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all of object in a json and put to a array with this code:

```
JSONArray texts = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("text");
```

Comment: This ain't `GSON` though.